# How to SQL fetch last 52 iso weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working with weeks that starts on Mondays. I was asked to get data for the last 52 weeks. So I use iso_week. 
The code below is grabbing week 1 of 2018.

```
 SELECT  YEAR(DATEADD(day, 26 - DATEPART(isoww, [ShipDate]), [ShipDate]))as ISOYEAR
       ,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, [ShipDate]) as ISOWEEK
      ,SUM([Ordered])
      ,SUM([Shipped])
  FROM [dbo].[DailyOrders]
  where product = 100203
  and DC='NY'
  and DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, [ShipDate]) >= -52
  and YEAR(DATEADD(day, 26 - DATEPART(isoww, [ShipDate]), [ShipDate]))>=2018
  GROUP BY YEAR(DATEADD(day, 26 - DATEPART(isoww, [ShipDate]), 
  [ShipDate])),DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, [ShipDate])
  ORDER BY 1
```

However,last 52 weeks should be from 2018 week 6 and not week 2018 week 1. 
Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you do an `INNER JOIN` on a sub-query who has all of the 52 last weeks. (with dates as a jointure condition).

Create a temporary table, and `UPDATE` on it with a `WHILE` loop and `DATEADD` function for every week. You can do all of this in a stored procedure.

Comment: are you saying build the 52 weeks temp table?

Comment: For exemple, that was I'm thinking about but this is not the only solution.

Comment: Create a stored procedure for this and you are good. And if you want to re-use the last 52 weeks in other queries you can make a permanent table.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Build a temp or regular table with the Dates, ISOWeek and RankField right? But how would I rank from 52 to 1 week?  May be do a for loop stepping down from 52 to 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting something like this:

```
 [ShipDate] >= dateadd(week, -52, getdate())
```

Of course, you want this by week, so:

```
 [ShipDate] >= dateadd(week, -52, dateadd(day, - datepart(dw, getdate()), convert(date, getdate())))
```